# Why do we need equals and hashcode when defining a composite key class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this class and followed a tutorial on creating a composite key class in spring boot, may I know whose calling this equals and hashcode and what are its purpose when mapping the object to the database tables.

```java
public class CustomerOrderPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomerOrderPK that = (CustomerOrderPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(customerId, that.customerId) && Objects.equals(orderId, that.orderId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(customerId, orderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: [The JPA specification says that all entity identifiers should be serializable and implement `equals` and `hashCode`. So, an `Embeddable` that is used as a composite identifier must be `Serializable` and implement `equals` and `hashCode`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). I don't know the nitty-gritty details of Hibernate implementation, but I'm assuming it's used by [IdentityMap](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html), or some other class in the framework to keep track of entities, detect duplicates etc.

Answer (score 1):

The composite key class represents the primary key of an entity, and therefore, it should be unique. Hibernate uses `equals` and `hashcode` methods internally to identify the uniqueness, compare objects, and check for duplications. To make these operations in Java, you have to implement `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Implementing `equals` and `hashcode` methods, you specify your custom business logic. In your example, the `CustomerOrderPK` guarantees that a **customer** cannot have the same **order** twice because `CustomerOrderPK` is the primary key.
If you don't override the `equals` and `hashcode`, Hibernate wouldn't know how to compare the objects and `CustomerOrderPK` couldn't be considered a primary key.